# Pass date range between two separate columns in SQL Server 2012 and above

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to select records as per my given inputs date range in SQL Server.

This means that my table is having the following records:

```
ProposedStartDate, ProposedEndDate, Roomid, Childid
2016-11-01         2016-11-31         111     10001
2016-12-15         2016-12-31         121     10001
2017-01-01         2017-01-31         111     10001
2017-01-01         2017-01-31         121     10001    
2017-02-01         2017-02-28         111     10001
```

Now, I want to display records with unique roomid from between dates. Inputs are: '2016-12-25' and '2017-01-15'

Comment: I am trying to retrieve data through WHERE ProposedStartDate BETTWEEN InputStartDate AND InputstrEndDate...but not showing correct data even I've also tried InputStartDate >= ProposedStartDate OR InputEndDate <=ProposedEndDate

Comment: As I said, **what have you tried so far**? That would be demonstrated by an [edit] to your post that contains a SQL statement which tries to retrieve the data you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, this should work

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE(ProposedStartDate varchar(10), ProposedEndDate varchar(10), Roomid int, Childid INT)
insert into @dates values ('2016-11-01' , '2016-11-31' , 111 , 10001)
insert into @dates values ('2016-12-15' , '2016-12-31' , 121 , 10001)
insert into @dates values ('2017-01-01' , '2017-01-31' , 111 , 10001)
insert into @dates values ('2017-01-01' , '2017-01-31' , 121 , 10001)    
insert into @dates values ('2017-02-01' , '2017-02-28' , 111 , 10001)


select * from @dates
         where CONVERT(datetime,ProposedStartDate)>=CONVERT(datetime, '2016-12-25' ) 
         and CONVERT(datetime,ProposedStartDate)<=CONVERT(datetime, '2017-01-15' )
```

Result is:

```
*-----------------*-----------------*--------*-------*
|ProposedStartDate|ProposedEndDate  |Roomid  |Childid|
*-----------------*-----------------*--------*-------*
|2017-01-01       |2017-01-31       |111     |10001  |
*-----------------*-----------------*--------*-------*
|2017-01-01       |2017-01-31       |   121  |10001  |
*-----------------*-----------------*--------*-------*
```